# How to understand $\int_{-a}^{a} f(|x|) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

[image]

Find $\int_{-6}^{6} f(|x|) dx$.

My (possibly incorrect?) solution:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-6}^{6} f(|x|) dx
&= \int_{-6}^{0} f(|x|) dx + \int_{0}^{6} f(|x|) dx \\
&= \int_{6}^{0} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx \\
&= -\int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx \\
&=0
\end{align*}

In which case, the function itself is irrelevant. So is it always the case that $\int_{-a}^a f(|x|)=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Your second line is wrong.  The first integral should instead be:
$$\int_{-6}^{0} f(|x|) dx = \int_{-6}^{0} f(-x) dx$$
Now perform a $u$-substitution with $u=-x$:
$$\int_{-6}^{0} f(-x) dx = -\int_{6}^{0} f(u) du = \int_{0}^{6} f(u) du$$
So the original integral is:
\begin{align}
\int_{-6}^6 f(|x|) dx
&= 2 \int_0^6 f(x) dx \\
&= 2 \left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_1^4 f(x) dx + \int_4^5 f(x) dx + \int_5^6 f(x) dx \right) \\
&= 2 (2 + 12 + 2 - 2) = 28
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to share a graph of what f(|x|) looks like?

Comment: It is the reflection across the $y$-axis of the portion of the graph of $f(x)$ that is to the right of the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

$f(|x|)$ is even function, so for integral in symmetric limits holds
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{a}f(|x|)\,dx=2\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to share a graph of what f(|x|) looks like for this specific example?

Comment: It is same from the left of $0$ as to the right.